# How is it possible to achive O(log n) power function a^n by only using recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

Below, the purpose of the code is to compute power of an integer.
My friend told me that the time complexity of this algorithm is O(log n).
But, in fact the number of function calls is not equal to logn.
For example, power(2, 9) calls power functions 5 times (including the calling power(2,9)), while power(2, 8) calls power function 4 times (including the calling power(2,8).
Nevertheless the number of bits needed for 8 and 9 are same, the numbers of function calls are different.

Why does this happen? Is this really O(log n) algorithm?

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                    
int power(int a, int n) {
  if(n == 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  if(n == 1) {
    return a;
  }
  if (n%2 == 0) {
    return power(a*a, n/2);
  }else{
    return a * power(a, n - 1);
  }
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    printf("pow(%d, %d) = %d\n", 2, i, power(2, i));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement, and step into function calls. That will allow you to see exactly what happens with e.g `power(2, 8)` and `power(2, 9)`.

Comment: You can put a `printf` at the top of the function, and print `a` and `n` to see why 9 takes one extra call.

Comment: Check out this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/ . It explains exactly how you can achieve O(logn) by making it a recursion problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is O(logN), but it could be made slightly more efficient.

Note that hereafter, a log is a log base 2.

You have log(n) calls of `power(a*a,n/2)`, and a call to `power(a, n-1)` for every bit set in *n*.

The number of bits set in *n* is at most log(n) +1.

Thus, the number of calls to `power` is at most log(n)+log(n)+1. For instance, when *n* = 15, the sequence of calls is

```
power(15), power(14), power(7), power(6), power(3), power(2), power(1)
```

log(n)+log(n)+1 = 3+3+1 = 7

Here is a more efficient implementation that has only log(n)+2 calls of `power`.

```
int power(int a, int n) {
  if(n == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (n&1 == 0) {
    return power(a*a, n/2);
  }else{
    return a * power(a*a, n/2);
  }
}
```

In this case the sequence of calls when *n* = 15 is

```
power(15), power(7), power(3), power(1), power(0)
```

I removed the `if (n == 1)` condition because we can avoid this test that would be performed log(n) time by adding one call to `power`.

We then have log(n)+2 calls to power which is better than 2log(n)+1.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the algorithm remains Ο(lg*N*) even with the extra calls for the odd number case is because the number of extra calls is bounded by a constant. In the worst case, *N/2* is odd at each iteration, but this would only double the number of extra calls (the constant is 2). That is, at worst, there will be 2lg*N* calls to complete the algorithm.

---

To more easily observe that the algorithm is Ο(lg*N*), you can rewrite the function to always reduce the power by half at each iteration, so that at worst case, there are only lg*N* calls. To leverage tail recursion, you can add a function parameter to accumulate the carried multiplier from the odd *N*.

```
int power_i (int a, unsigned N, int c) {
    if (N == 0) return c;
    return power_i(a*a, N/2, N%2 ? a*c : c);
}

int power (int a, unsigned N) {
    return power_i(a, N, 1);
}
```

The advantage of tail recursion is that the optimized code will be converted into a simple loop by most modern C compilers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BCsIwEEX3OcXfCGlJqnZpW7xBXHgAiTHWbFJJUhTUs8ekVARxYIb5M8z7c5T@EqOSAW1b4YleKfB7SvCdB0/NHnwAJ8YGXIebdgcDmoVkGK03vdUnCIY8UgUeBCnMGVSg67Aq4HQYnYVqps2sZhKVZcKIZZ3KosYWslTYJE5DXuRr@cfw4/TLY/mX9XRfxfgG)

Answer (score 0):

The power function has two base cases: n = 0 and n = 1.

The power function has two recursive calls. Only one of them is made in any given call.

Let's first consider the case when n is even: In that case, the recursive call is made with n / 2.

If all calls would use this case, then you half n in each call down until you reach 1. This is indeed `log(n)` calls (plus 1 for the base case).

The other case, when n is odd, reduces n only by one. If all calls would end up using this recursive call then the function would be called n times; clearly not logarithmic but linear thus.

**But** what happens to an odd number when you subtract one from it? It becomes an even number. Thus the feared linear behaviour mentioned above cannot occur.

Worst case is: n is odd, thus use second recursive call. Now n is even, thus first recursive call. Now n is odd, this use second, ... and so on down until n is one. In that case every second call reduces n to n / 2. Therefore you need `2 * log(n)` calls then (plus one for the base case).

So yes, this is in `O(log(n))`. This algorithm is often called [binary exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Answer (score 0):

This is another notation of how to do it :

```
long double xpow(long double a, int b ) {
    double ret = 1;
        while (b) {
            if (b & 1)
                ret = ret  * a ;
            a = a * a ;
            b >>= 1;
        }
     return ret;
}
```